# Subtracting From Int And Printing

Tags: python

I am making a text based game and have been doing just fine but now but I have run into an error with `int`.  My code so far looks like this:

```
money = 500
print("You Have $500 To Spend On Your City.  The Population Is 0 People")
input_var3 = input("What Will You Spend Your Money On?  A House Or A Restraunt. ")
if input_var3 == "House":
    money - 100
    print("You Have Spent Your Money On A House")
    print("You Now Have $" + money)
if input_var3 == "Restraunt":
    money - 150
    print("You Have Spent Your Money On A Restraunt")
    print("You Now Have $" + money)
```

Your money is equal to 500 dollars but if you spend it on a house or restraunt you will have less money and the shell will print how much you have left.  However I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\City Text.py", line 11, in <module>
    print("You Now Have $" + money)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I have realized that I must make a sting instead of the Int but I am not sure how to do this.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I've edited out that last part of your question, don't worry nobody will downvote you since you have shown effort and your question is not off topic

Comment: I can't say for everyone, but I agree with @jamylak that generally we don't downvote "simple" questions, rather questions that show no effort from the asker (_send-me-teh-codez_ questions, etc.)

Comment: @user2398805 you should have `money = money - 100` etc..., instead of `money - 100`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `money` variable is an *integer*. You can't mix integers with strings when concatenating them together. Use the `str()` function, which converts an integer to a string:

```
print("You Now Have $" + str(money))
```

Also, I think you're intending to take 100 away from the money value. `money - 100` just returns `500 - 100`, which is `400`. If you want to make `money` equal to `400`, do:

```
money -= 100
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
money = money - 100
```

Comment: Finally an answer addressing both problems, +1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the value inside variable.

```
if input_var3 == "House":
    money -= 100   # Notice the usage of -=
    print("You Have Spent Your Money On A House")
    print("You Now Have $" + str(money))   # Type casting
if input_var3 == "Restraunt":
    money = money - 150  # Same as -=
    print("You Have Spent Your Money On A Restraunt")
    print("You Now Have $" + str(money))   # Type casting
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
print("You Now Have $" + str(money))
```

you can't concatenate a string with a number so convert your number into a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str()` function. For example:

```
print("You Now Have $" + str(money))
```